Work done in an electric field, when both the charges are moving
We know the work done on a charge by another charge when one is fixed and other is moving but what if the other charge is not fixed?   Both the charges can move, what will the work be when the separation between both of them reduces by a distance $r$ radially instead when one is fixed and the other moves a distance $r$ radially towards the fixed one?

This is an often asked problem which can be solved by using conservation of linear momentum and conservation of energy.

Do the charges begin and end at rest, or do they end up colliding?

@bob the displacement between them changes by r , no other force do work.

@Farcher I just wanted to know the derivation if both the charges are brought closer together , instead of only one being moved. Usually books derive the work done when bringing two charges together from infinity by assuming one at rest but i would love to know how we will derive the total work on the system when both the charges are brought simultaneously.

If two unlike charges are released from rest they will accelerate towards one another until they either collide or are somehow brought to rest at some final separation. Which is it?

In other words, what I am asking you is whether or not the charges have kinetic energy at their final separation?

@BobD they are brought to rest at some final seperation , what will be the work done by the electric field ?

OK thanks for clarification. See my answer.

The work done by a conservative field, such as an electric field, equals the negative of the change in potential energy, in this case electrostatic potential energy, or
$$W=-\Delta U$$
The change in electrostatic potential energy of the two charge configuration from the initial to final separation is given by
$$\Delta U=U_{2}-U_{1}= k\biggl(\frac{Q_{1}Q_{2}}{r_2}- \frac{Q_{1}Q_{2}}{r_1}\biggr )$$
Where
$U_2$, $U_1$ = are the final and initial electrostatic potential energy of the two charge configuration, respectively.
$k$ = Coulomb's constant
$r_2$, $r_1$ = the final and initial separation where $r_{2}\lt r_{1}$
$Q_1$, $Q_2$ = point charges, in Coulombs. One being negative and the other positive (since you say they are attracted to one another).
Therefore
$$W=k\biggl(\frac{Q_{1}Q_{2}}{r_1}- \frac{Q_{1}Q_{2}}{r_2}\biggr )$$
Since the charges begin and end at rest, there is no change in kinetic energy. This means the net work done by an external agent and the electric field is zero.
Hope this helps.

So the work done by electric field to bring two charges from a seperation of r2 to r1 is equal to the change in potential energy.  Can we also think it like this ?   We can observe the work done by force on charge 1 from the reference frame of charge 2 and charge 1 brought closer from a seperation r1 to r2.

Sorry I don’t understand your last statement beginning with “We can observe…”

Sorry for not framing it properly , can we measure the work done by the force relative (we can set our coordinate system to one of the charges) to one of the charges ? i think the work done would still be the same.

@Srijeet I’m not sure what “work” you are talking about being the same. The total work as I gave in my answer? The work done by each charge on the other being the same?  Please clarify.

Yes! I think the total work done as given in your answer should be equal to the work done by one charge on the other , as one charge is static so no one work is done on it. I am sorry for troubling you as i am not that fluent in explaining my questions.

@Srijeet Try proving it to yourself. Do the calculation for each charge individually. Let the magnitude of one of the charges be twice that of the other. That means the electric field generated by one charge will be twice that of the other. Keep in mind that when you look at the final separation of the charge you you would only be accounting for the displacement of the other charge. Let me know what you find out. We might have to discuss your results in CHAT as the discussion may be lengthy. Good luck!

@Srijeet Have you proved it to yourself yet?

Yes! I think i have proved it , by integrating the force wrt to dr when the charge moves from a seperation r1 to r2 ,the work done on the charge by the static charge is negative of the change in potential energy of the system. This shows that , it doesn't matter if both the charges are moving or not the work done is always equal to the negative of the change in potential energy.

@Srijeet Correct. The change in potential energy (which is the negative of the work done by the conservative electrostatic force between the charges) is the same for an observer on Q1 where only Q2 is observed to move, an observer on Q2 where only Q1 is observed to move, and an observer on neither charge where both charges are observed to move.

For given charges, the change in potential energy  only depends on the change in separation between the charges. That change in separation is the same for all three observers. For different magnitude charges (e.g. $Q_{2}\gt Q_{1}$), which generate different magnitude electric fields (e.g. $E_{2}\gt E_{1}$), at any given separation the magnitude of the force on each charge is the same ($Q_{1}E_{2}=Q_{2}E_{1}$).

Thanks for helping!
